# How to make function friend of local class?

Tags: c++, friend-function, local-class

Please read the code to know the problem :

```
#include <iostream>

void fun(int value)
{
    //starts local class definition
    class test
    {
        int x;
    public:
        test(int a) : x(a) {}
        void display() const
        {
            std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
        }
    };
    //end of the definition
    test t1(value);
    t1.display();
    //if we write the statement t1.x=100; here .It will give us an error
    //because we can not access the private members from the enclosing function
    //now what should I do if I want to access the private members of the test class from fun function
}
int main()
{
    fun(5);
}
```

Should I make the fun function as friend for the local class(test). I was reading a book and there was said that we can achieve this by declaring the enclosing function as a `friend`. Now my problem is this I don't know how to make the enclosing function as a friend of the local class. Please, someone tell me how can I do so.

Comment: Why do you think you need to have a class like that inside a function?

Comment: Write a getX() method and return x inside.

Comment: Make it public?

Comment: @RSahu i am doing this for learning purpose

Comment: Since the class definition is inside the function and not accessible outside of the function, there is no real benefit to declaring any of its members as `private` to begin with since nobody else but the function will be accessing them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: function might return the class via `auto` though. and regular syntax of `friend` seems problematic

Comment: @Jarod42 If the function returns a local class using `auto`, the caller won't know about the class type and won't know how to access its contents anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Qualified call `friend void ::fun(int);` is a way:

```cpp
void fun(int value)
{
    //starts local class definition
    class test
    {
        friend void ::fun(int);
        int x;
    public:
        test(int a)
        {
            x=a;
        }
        void display()
        {
            std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
        }

    };
    //end of the definition
    test t1(value);
    t1.display();
    t1.x = 42;
    t1.display();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dGsebqvdx)

Notice than some old version of g++ reject it.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I make the fun function as friend for the local class(test)

It's unclear whether you *should*. It is often a good idea to avoid breaking the encapsulation that private members offer. Or conversely, if the encapsulation isn't needed, then maybe it would be simpler for the member to be public. But let's instead consider whether you *could*...

Standard says (quoting latest draft):

> [class.friend]
>
> If a friend declaration appears in a local class ([class.local]) and the name specified is an unqualified name, a prior declaration is looked up **without considering scopes that are outside the innermost enclosing non-class scope**.
> For a friend function declaration, if there is no prior declaration, the program is ill-formed. ...

If I interpret this legalese correctly, no unqualified name outside of the function body of  `fun` can be looked up. As far as I know, the declaration of `fun` itself is outside of that scope. However also as far as I know, nothing should prevent you from re-declaring the function:

```
void fun(int value)
{
    void fun(int); // (re)declaration within innermost enclosing non-class scope

    class test
    {
        friend void fun(int); // the friend declaration
```

This appears to work in Clang and MSVC, but not in GCC unfortunately, which still doesn't allow access to the private member. This may be a GCC bug.

Another option would be to declare the friend with a qualified name:

```
class test
{
    friend void ::fun(int); // qualified name
```

In which case the restriction above wouldn't apply. Unfortunately, GCC doesn't accept this either, and without the local re-declaration produces a diagnostic:

> error: friend declaration 'void fun(int)' in local class without prior local declaration

This looks like a separate bug, which reproduces whether declaring `::fun` or any other qualified function name as friend. I found an existing bugreport: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69410

Comment: Qualified call (`::fun`) is another alternative (also rejected by GCC :-/ ).

Comment: @Jarod42 I was just extending the answer :)

Comment: @Jarod42 But [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4MxM394Wa) all compilers, including gcc accept the program. Maybe coliru is using an old version of gcc that has the bug.

Answer (score 0):

First declare the function

```
void fun(int);
```

Then in class :

```
public:
friend void ::fun(int  );
```

Comment: I haven't succeed yet to compile that with gcc :-/

Answer (score 0):

Note that this [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69410) has now been [fixed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69410#c11) in GCC, and backported to versions 10 and up.